# How to add shadow and corner radius to UICollectionViewCell including the header and footer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building an app using UICollectionCompositionalLayouts in iOS, I want to recreate the following cell

[image: Collection View Cell with Shadow including Header and Footer]

The cell has a shadow and rounded corner on all sides, including the header and footer as if it would be part of the cell. When I try to recreate this appearance in my UICollectionViewCell, I can only add a Shadow to the header, everything else just gets ignored. The following is my cell

[image: My Collection View Cell]

No matter how I setup the individual collection view cells that make up that section, the shadow is never there and the cell doesn't appear to be connected like in the first image.

This is the code I do to setup the cell

**Code for the customization of the Header**

```
class HeaderWorkoutOfDay:UICollectionReusableView {


let mainView = UIView()

static let reuseIdentifier = String(describing: self)

static let elementKind = String(describing: self)


let programmeNameButton = UIButton(type: .system)

let workoutNameLabel = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    addSubview(mainView)
    
    mainView.snp.makeConstraints { (view) in
        view.top.left.bottom.right.equalToSuperview()
    }
    
    
    mainView.addSubview(programmeNameButton)
    mainView.addSubview(workoutNameLabel)
    costumizeViews()
    setupConstraints()
    
    
    
    
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func costumizeViews(){
    
    programmeNameButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)
    programmeNameButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    
    workoutNameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold)
    
    self.mainView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    
    self.mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    self.mainView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 200, green: 200, blue: 200).cgColor
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    
    
}

private func setupConstraints(){
    
    programmeNameButton.snp.makeConstraints { (button) in
        button.left.top.right.equalToSuperview().offset(8)
        button.bottom.equalTo(workoutNameLabel.snp.top).offset(-8)
    }
    
    
    workoutNameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (label) in
        label.left.equalToSuperview().offset(8)
        label.top.equalTo(programmeNameButton.snp.bottom).offset(8)
        label.bottom.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-8)
    }
    
}
```

}

The same setup I use for the individual cell and the footer, also a UICollectionReusableView

How could I recreate the appearance of the first image?

Comment: I would add background color to coll.view, and set the `collView.layer.maskedCorners` for the header and content as well.

Comment: Although a bit lengthier and dirtier, you could also add a background view to each cell, inset this view a few points from the edges of the cell, and add the shadow to that